# 英語のまま：ピアレビュー内のレビュー担当者統計

Tags: バグ, 英語

※『https://ja.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12666』から引用しています

> レビュー担当者統計
>   •KoRoN has approved 140 edit suggestions and rejected 7 edit suggestions and improved 2 edit suggestions
>   •mjy has approved 53 edit suggestions and rejected 2 edit suggestions and improved 0 edit suggestions
>
> 編集者統計
>   •Laclip が提案した編集は、0 件承認され、1 件却下されました

Answer (score 2):

> $UserName$ は提案された編集を、$ApprovalCount$件承認し、$RejectionCount$件却下し、$ImprovementCount$件改善しました

Transifex上で翻訳を登録しました。近日中にサイトに反映されるかと思います。